# Unmounted volume asks for password at login

Tags: password, automount

I have edited the `/etc/fstab` to not automount at login one of the volumes on my partition (the one, which is not the booting).
   The volume is encrypted. So, at login, though it does not automount, BUT asks nevertheless for the password. When I introduce the password, it does not mount, as expected.
   The problem is, how to make it NOT to ask for the password at login?
   Thank you!